# FactoryGirl creates instances with faulty attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

*Disclaimer:The model name and attributes are changed due to security issues!*

```
class Human < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  attr_accessible :ssn

  validates :ssn, uniqueness: { scope: ... }

  validate :ssn_validator

  def ssn_validator
    #some regexp for checking
    ...
  end
end
```

And the FactoryGirl factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do    
  factory :human do
    ssn '123456789'
  end
end
```

And in my test I test my ssn_validator, i.e. I create some Human instances with wrong ssn values.

```
class SisIdentifiableTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context 'human ssn' do
    should 'be valid' do 
      assert FactoryGirl.build(:human).valid?
    end
    should 'be invalid if containing a & symbol' do 
      assert !FactoryGirl.build(:human, ssn:'12345678&').valid?
    end
    should 'be invalid if sorter than 9 symbols' do 
      assert !FactoryGirl.build(:human, ssn:'12345678').valid?
    end
  end 
end
```

The test results:

```
HumanTest
  human ssn be valid                              #pass
  human ssn be invalid if containing a & symbol   #fail
  human ssn be invalid if sorter than 9 symbols   #fail
```

First, I thought that my **ssn_validator** is somehow faulty. But that was not the case.

All human instances were valid, because somehow the ssn in valid? call was cached.

I mean that valid? method tests the human instance against the default '123456789' valid value(provided by the :human factory), not against supposed **ssn:'12345678'** or **ssn:'12345678&'**

In a sample:

```
human = FactoryGirl.build(:human, ssn:'there be dragons')
human.ssn             #'there be dragons'
human.ssn_validator   #false   - because the sting is not valid
human.valid?          #true
```

**My question:** How to test validation with FactoryGirl? Is there other method like valid? working not against cached attributes? Or I'm creating the tested instances using the wrong way?

Comment: Your sample tests a value different than your tests. Can you post the body of your SSN validator? Also, do you really need to change your model names and attributes? That's just adding another layer where things could be mistranslated.

Answer (score 0):

FactoryGirl is not really for testing validations.  It's a convenience to help you set up your test data.  The `build` method will not cause any validation on the model because it's really just doing `Human.new` and then setting the attributes from your factory.  Validation won't happen until you actually try to save the model.

(The `create` method of FactoryGirl would validate the object as it's the same as `Human.create`, and so has to save the object.  Again it sets the attributes from the factory.)

Is it possible you can post the code of your ssn_validator method?  For example, does it do something like `errors.add(:ssn, ...)` if validation fails?  This would be needed for the `valid?` method to then realise there has been a validation failure.

The way I read your question, it does imply the error is in the validator.  When you say:

```
human ssn be invalid if containing a & symbol   #fail
```

that implies your validation of not working.  This is an example of an invalid ssn, and if the validator correctly picks it up your test would be expected to pass, not fail.

Apologies if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Build won't cause validation but he also calls 'valid?'

Comment: Yes I know; I meant that FactoryGirl by itself is not for testing validations.  The fact that valid? is called and not working implies, to me, that the fault is within the ssn_validator method.